# Will Django update passwords that doesn't have the current password hasher?

Tags: python, django, passwords, bcrypt

If I update `PASSWORD_HASHERS` in Django settings, will Django automatically update the passwords of users that were hashed with a previous algorithm when they sign in?

I'm working with a table of users and passwords where some has been hashed with sha1 or md5 and some with bcrypt. I want to make sure that as users sign in, their passwords are updated with bcrypt so that I can progressively become more secure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, "When users log in, if their passwords are stored with anything other than the preferred algorithm, Django will automatically upgrade the algorithm to the preferred one." [Relevant docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/passwords/#password-upgrading).

Comment: Sorry, didn't know what to google for here, should have read the docs more properly. Thanks for the help! :)